# How can I change the terminal in VS Code to the VS Live Share Space rather than my local drive?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have connected to my team's VS Code Live Share workspace from my VS Code App. However it doesn't let me access the terminal for that space, instead being a proxy of my local terminal and the files contained under it on my personal machine.
[VS Code Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ74R.png).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a due to the `liveshare.autoShareTerminals` setting. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/security#sharing-a-terminal), which state:

> In VS Code, terminals are automatically shared read-only by default. However, you can disable this by adding the following to settings.json:
>
> ```json
> "liveshare.autoShareTerminals": false
> ```

(the Live Share host has to make that change to their settings).

See also [the docs for sharing terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/liveshare/use/share-server-visual-studio-code#share-a-terminal), which state:

> By default, terminals aren't shared because they give guests at least read-only access to the output of commands you run (if not the ability to run commands themselves). This default configuration allows you to run commands in local terminals with reduced risk and share only when you need to. And only hosts can start shared terminals. This limitation prevents guests from starting one up and doing something you aren't expecting.
>
> As a host, you can share a terminal from the **Live Share** or the Live Share **Explorer** tab. Select the **Share terminal** item or button:
>
> [image]
>
> At this point, you can choose whether to make the terminal read-only or read/write. When the terminal is read/write, everyone can type in the terminal, including the host. So, as a host, you can easily intervene if a guest is doing something you don't like.
>
> To be safe, you should *give read/write access to guests only when you know they actually need it*. Stick with read-only terminals when you just want the guests to see the output of commands you run. Keep in mind that read/write access gives guests the same access to your terminal that you have. They can run any command on your computer that you can.